# How can I blacklist a specific site client side?

Tags: windows, browser, blacklist

Long story short, my educational institution uses proxy software on the laptops it issues students. When a student visits a prohibited site, internet access is completely disabled for several minutes. This applies to all requests - embeds, apis, you name it. So, as you can expect, the internet is a veritable minefield of prohibited sites that frequently lock down my computer, even when I don't interntionally visit them. Is there any way to prohibit a web browser - say, Chrome or Edge - from even loading a specific site?

I've poked around a little, but everything I've seen seems to want things along the lines of registry editing and additional third party software. I don't have admin on my loaner, so this isn't really helpful...